# jquery onclick fadein effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am just starting to learn jquery with very little JS knowledge (long story short - I'm told it helps provide shortcuts - if I had time I would learn JS properly).

With that out of the way, I am trying to essentially create a scrolling marquee or multi-frame hero banner, whatever you want to call it.  I don't want any automation, I am looking specifically for the end user to click a button/image to change the marquee image.

I am having issues with my jquery as is AND I'd like to ask for assistance on another piece I am struggling with, which is hiding the image that is currently showing.

1. what is wrong with my current jquery that it will not work appropriately?
   a. file is loaded at top of the page
   b. when I execute this ($("#imgd2").fadeIn;) part of the jquery it works in firebug, but within the click function it does not...
2. how could I go about looking to see what image is currently showing, hide that and fade in the appropriate image.  For example, img1 is displayed by default, if i click on img3, how can I hide image 1 before fading in marquee 3?

//html - forgive the laziness
//I am showing the first image by default and hiding the other two images on the page.

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 450px;" id="img-container">

<div id="imgd1" style="width: 432px; height: 398px; position: absolute; background-image: url(img1.jpg); background-size: cover;"></div>
<div id="imgd2" style="width: 432px; height: 398px; position: absolute; display: none; background-image: url(img2.jpg); background-size: cover;"></div>
<div id="imgd3" style="width: 432px; height: 398px; position: absolute; display: none; background-image: url(img3.jpg); background-size: cover;"></div>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 438px; left: 322px;" id="bttns">
<img id="img1" src="active.png">
<img id="img2" src="active.png">
<img id="img3" src="active.png"> 
</div>

</div>
```

//jquery
//On click of a particular button, I want to fadein the appropriate image

```
$("#img1").click(function () {
$("#imgd1").fadeIn;
});

$("#img2").click(function () {
$("#imgd2").fadeIn;
});

$("#img3").click(function () {
$("#imgd3").fadeIn;
});
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: To get a property that would work. So that would be the unexecuted `jQuery.fadeIn` function. To execute a function you need parentheses. Of course, if you did `var fi = $('#img1').fadeIn; fi();` the context would change, creating problems, but that would be something you'll learn later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fadeIn` is a function, you need to invoke it

```
$("#imgd3").fadeIn();
```

Instead of writing a click handler for each of the `imgd` elements, you can target all of them(by adding a class `imgd`) and use a `data-*` attribute to specify the image(`data-target` attribute with the id of the image) to be displayed. Also add a class `img` to all the images so that we can hide it easily.

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 450px;" id="img-container">
    <div id="imgd1" class="imgd" style="width: 432px; height: 398px; position: absolute; background-image: url(//placehold.it/432x398/ff0000); background-size: cover;"></div>
    <div id="imgd2" class="imgd" data-target="#img2" style="width: 432px; height: 398px; position: absolute; display: none; background-image: url(//placehold.it/432x398/00ff00); background-size: cover;"></div>
    <div id="imgd3" class="imgd" data-target="#img3" style="width: 432px; height: 398px; position: absolute; display: none; background-image: url(//placehold.it/432x398/0000ff); background-size: cover;"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 438px; left: 322px;" id="bttns">
        <img id="img1" class="img" data-target="#imgd1" src="//placehold.it/32/ff0000" />
        <img id="img2" class="img" data-target="#imgd2" src="//placehold.it/32/00ff00" />
        <img id="img3" class="img" data-target="#imgd3" src="//placehold.it/32/0000ff" />
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $imgds = $('.imgd');
    $('.img').click(function () {
        var $target = $($(this).data('target'));
        $imgds.not($target).hide();
        $target.stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/94S95/)

Comment: thx for attempting to help!  Something is not working correctly here.  I noticed the misspelling of data-target in the html, but that did not work.  Any thoughts here?  It's like my images are not clickable to make the JS work...

Comment: @user2828701 Sorry I made the `imgd` element as clickable instead of `img` element, see the update and the demo

Comment: @scrowler sorry which is the duplicated id

Comment: @ArunPJohny I jumped the gun, didn't see the "d" :) apologies

Comment: @ArunPJohny looks like your code is working on a new page for me, but is not working on the page I need it to.  The divs and images are being served by php...not sure if that would impact anything...but I most likely have some sort of typo which is causing this to not work...thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

it must have a parenthesis :-)

`$("#imgd5").fadeIn();`

for question #2..heres my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5PP4z/2/

Comment: @Bonakid thx for the help.  I had when working in firebug, somehow it was left out of my post.  Any thoughts on the second question?

Comment: i updated my answer hope it helps. P.S. i use button cause my internet connection is sloooowww...